# Geoserver error 401 using WMS

Tags: geoserver, wms

I've this problem when I try to use an URL of a map WMS for example

Prueba de conexión fallida [Test connection failed]: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://focosdecalor.conae.gov.ar/geoserver/FocosDeCalor/wms?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.0&SERVICE=WMS

what is this?

Comment: There is something a little odd going on with the service, you request version 1.1.0, the service responds with a document that is called `getcapabilities_1.3.0.xml` but is actually a WMS 1.1.1 document...

Answer (score 1):

It worked fine for me when I tried it in QGIS, and just with a browser for the GetCapabilities.

Most likely you are working in an environment that has an outgoing web proxy, and you haven't configured it for whatever client(s) you are trying.